# How to fix parsing error unexpected token

Tags: javascript, html

I am seeing **ERROR:** parsing error unexpected token carts in main.js file.

main.js

```
let carts = document.querySelectorAll(".add-cart"); // add-cart is the class name from below <a> element.
```

HTML

```
<div class ="container">
<div class ="image">
   <img src= "Images/CLIP-IN EXTENSIONS - NATURAL STRAIGHT.jpg">
   <h3  style ="text-align: center"> Natural Straight</h3>
   <h3 style ="text-align: center">$ 95,00</h3>
   <a class ="add-cart cart1" href=" "> Add cart</a>     
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that's definitely the line which causes the problem? Doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong with it - no errors or anything. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mea1nqf3/ . In order for us to help you, please post the exact error message and stack trace, and the line it actually occurs on. The only other way I can think that this line might cause a problem is if you're trying to run it in an older version of Internet Explorer, so please confirm to us what browser you are using. Thanks

Comment: The problem could be on the line before it.

Comment: @ADyson  Iam using google chrome Version 83.0.4103.61

Comment: ok so that rules out the browser issue. So if you require further help, please now update us with the other information I requested.

Comment: @ADyson The Exact error I am seeing is at line 1 with red color in Main.js file as ERROR:Parsing error: Unexpected token carts. and what is stack trace? and I am assuming that the problem is with document.querySelector because when ever I come across document.querseclecotor in other lines of code I see this issue. could you please help me

Comment: The stack trace is a list of functions which the application was in the middle of when an error occurred. This is very useful because it doesn't only show you where the error happened, but also how the program ended up in that place of the code. In the console you can often see this by clicking the error message to expand it.

Comment: Also, in Chrome and other browsers, on the right-hand side of the entry for each error message will be the exact line on which it occurred. That text is even a link you can click which will take you to the exact place in the code. So you don't need to "assume" which line might the problem, the computer will tell you specifically!

Comment: "when ever I come across document.querseclecotor in other lines of code I see this issue"...this sounds unlikely, that function is not, by itself, a problem. More likely it's a symptom of something else.

Comment: So....you've mentioned "line 1" already - is that the line which contains the `let carts = ` code, or not? If not, please tell us what that line contains. It is possible that the root cause of the problem is actually somewhere else - the error is saying it doesn't expect "carts" to be the next thing it sees in the code when trying to understand it. That implies that maybe something else was written incorrectly just beforehand.

Comment: In conclusion, if you want some help, you need to tell us more information, and be as specific and detailed as you can. What you've shown us so far doesn't allow us to reproduce or understand your issue or where it may be coming from.